# General algebraic result obtained from consideration on $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic, model-theory, fields, p-adic-numbers

There are results in field theory which are obtained from, let's say, the complex numbers and then generalized to all algebraically closed fields.

For instance, the fact that a polynomial $P$ admits a multiple root iff $P$ and $P'$ have a common root (this is a basic algebraic result, but we may consider any result involving derivatives as being more "natural" on a field where derivatives come with a "natural" interpretation).

By studying field theory from a logical perspective, we can see that $\mathit{ACF}_0$ (the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$) is complete and that explains how some results proven over $\mathbb{C}$ are still valid in the more general context of $\mathit{ACF}_0$.

Another example is [Ax's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem) in which a result which is natural in the context of finite fields transfers to $\mathbb{C}$.

My question is: are there results which are "natural" in the context of $p$-adic numbers or their algebraic closures $\mathbb{C}_p$ and which transfer nicely over other fields (over which they may not be so "natural")?

Comment: I'm not sure I see in what sense the derivative is more natural over $\mathbb{C}$ than over $\mathbb{C}_p$ though.

Comment: "Birational Calabi–Yau $n$-folds have equal Betti numbers" by Batyrev provides an example, although this was later proven by different means by Kontsevich.  "Mirror symmetry for moduli spaces of Higgs bundles via $p$-adic integration" by Groechenig, Wyss, and Ziegler provides a more recent example.

Comment: @SimonHenry Agreed, and ditto for any topological field. And indeed, even better, for polynomials the "derivative" is the "best first order approximation", which means that for any ring $R$ and any $f(x)\in R[x]$, we define $f'(x)\in R[x]$ to be the unique polynomial in $R[x]$ such that in the two-variable polynomial ring $R[x,y]$ we have  $$f(x+y)-f(x)-f'(x)y\in y^2 R[x,y].$$

Comment: @SimonHenry "natural" is very subjective, let's just say that derivative over the reals is closer to the layman intuition of the "slope of the tangent", and I believe it's also how the idea of a derivation emerged historically (of course, it's debatable whether the chronology of discoveries is a good proxy for a concept of "naturalness"). As for the complex derivative, it can be visualized (I don't know how to visualize p-adic derivation).

Comment: @WillSawin That is interesting. Would you be able to explain the key points that make these results "easier" to prove using p-adic analysis? (maybe an answer would be appropriate)

Comment: Out of curiosity since it’s being discussed in the comments. Is there a notion of a p-Adic line (perhaps nothing at all like the lines we know in $\mathbb{R}^n$) but at least one can say “smooth” p-adic functions look locally like p-adic lines if one zooms in enough (in the p-adic sense)? Without knowing geometrically what these lines are we can still at least make sense of the idea of the derivative and smoothness. I can imagine there’s a nice fractal called the P-adic line, and there’s some other fractal which is our smooth function but when I zoom in on this fractal it looks like the line

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal Well, it's common to define lines over any field as one-dimensional affine spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Matt Baker gave a proof that $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ is cyclic (always a bit mysterious, as there's no "natural" generator) by first looking at a related result in characteristic $0$ using an extension of the $p$-adic numbers and then reducing mod $p$. See [here](https://mattbaker.blog/2013/11/07/primitive-roots-discrete-logarithms-and-the-interplay-between-p-adic-and-complex-numbers/).

Comment: That is interesting, but regarding the transfer, it seems to be the (first-order) theorem
"The group of p-th roots of unity is cyclic" that is transferred from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}_p$.
In my question I asked for the other way.

Comment: @Weier I viewed this as transferring the result from the field $\mathbf Q_p$ to he field $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Comment: It works in that case, but it doesn't use the completeness of $ACF_0$ since $F_p$ is neither algebraically close nor of characteristic $0$. Still, I think the result is interesting (although it could be argued that the Hansel lemma itself is more complicated than usual proof for cyclicity of $(Z/pZ)^{\times}$)